# How to bring Browser on top when opening it from WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

When I click on button it'l open URL in IE but IE browser is not coming in front.

I am currently using below code :

```
using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {

                browser.Navigate(
                  new Uri(getUri(serverConfig, guid), UriKind.Absolute),
                  Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                  null, null
                );
            }
```

my requirement is browser should open front of the WPF application.

Comment: `WebBrowser` is as control, which should be hosted inside window or other container. It doesn't open the separate IE window

Comment: You should try something like this: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://google.com");`

Comment: @sthotakura  our requirement url should open in IE everytime.. if i use process.start it will open in default browser. can you uggest on this?

Comment: Refer to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `Process` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> our requirement url should open in IE everytime.. if i use process.start it will open in default browser. can you suggest on this?

This opens IE on Windows 10:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe",
    "http://stackoverflow.com");
```

On previous versions of Windows, you may replace the first argument with the value "iexplore".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve what you said, you can do this :)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void FocusBrowser()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

    //TODO Need add additional code to filter
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
        {
            continue;
        }
        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);

        return;
    }
}



using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
{
     browser.Navigate(
             new Uri(getUri(serverConfig, guid), UriKind.Absolute),
             Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
             null, 
             null);

     FocusBrowser();
}
```